# Jenkins: build dependencies on demand

Tags: jenkins, dependencies

In Jenkins with job chaining you can define job-dependencies by triggering a dependent job after building the dependency, e.g.:

```
BaseLib has been built -> build MainProject
```

Maybe I've just been searching for the wrong terms but I didn't figure it out yet: can I make Jenkins trigger building the dependency when it's needed for the dependent job?

E.g. I have some job `BaseLib` which is a dependency for `MainProject`. I don't want to build `BaseLib` every time the source code changes but I want to build `MainProject` periodically e.g. every day at 5pm. Instead of *building* `BaseLib` every time it's source code changes I want Jenkins to just *invalidate* the artifacts and build it only on demand.

In other words: I basically want to make Jenkins to do what `make` does - build what's needed to build what I want it to build.

Is that possible? What are the terms I have to look for?

Answer (score 0):

You can setup build your dependency project before BaseLib
That`s a build step "**Trigger/call builds on other projects**" you can setup parent build to wait until child build has been finished.

Look for: [Parameterized Build](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build), [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) and [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin).